# Ulterior method to contains?

Tags: java, file-io, boolean

I am trying to see if my file contains more than 1 field. When I enter agentName and agent_id into the scanner it checks the file for the entered values. It work with just one condition in the if statement. When I put the second statement in the if after the boolean && it doesn't return anything.

Has anyone got any idea what I can do? I have tried with a nested if as well, but it was the same story.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance!!!!

```
package p;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Login {

    public static final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Do you want to Login as a Club or an Agent? ");
        System.out.println("Enter C for club or A for Agent or press e to exit !!! ");

        char ch = input.next().charAt(0);

        if (ch == 'A' || ch == 'a') {

            String agentName = "";
            String agent_id = "";
            String line;

            try {

                FileReader fr = new FileReader("Agent.txt");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

                System.out.println("Please enter the name of the Agent \n");
                agentName = input.next();
                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("Please enter the Agents id ");
                agent_id = input.next();
                System.out.println("\n");

                List<String> playerInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    if (line.toLowerCase().contains(agentName.toLowerCase())
                            && line.toLowerCase().contains(agent_id.toLowerCase())) {

                        int numLines = 2;//represents the number of lines in the file I want to show
                        playerInfo.add(line);

                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && numLines >= 0) {
                            playerInfo.add(line);
                            numLines--;
                            System.out.println("Agent found...... \n");
                            System.out.println("Loading.....");
                            System.out.println(playerInfo);
                            break;

                        } // inner while

                    } // if

                } // while

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless both values are on the same line, it will return false.  You need to use `||` instead of `&&`.  Try the following:

```
            if (line.toLowerCase().contains(agentName.toLowerCase())
                  || line.toLowerCase().contains(agent_id.toLowerCase())) {
                     // rest of code here
```

Comment: Thanks man, that helped a lot. Would you know off the top of your head a way I can check both values? I'm trying to make a make shift login.

Comment: I'm guessing how you're doing this but you would need to collect the information as you are doing, and then check the values against some data base (e.g. some protected file of players and their passwords or ID's).